# FreeMarker arithmetic operations in list iteration java

Tags: java, freemarker

I need to do some arithmetic operations in freemarker template. I have a list of objects and i need to apply the arithmetic operation like below...

```
<#list order.orderDetails as orderDetail>
    <tr>
        <#assign orderTotal=${orderDetail.quantity}*${orderDetail.price}>
        <td>${orderDetail.product.productName}</td>
        <td>${orderDetail.quantity}</td>
        <td>${orderDetail.price}</td>
        <td>orderTotal</td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

I need order total value using this calculation but it doesn't work. It shows

> error in syntax. assign tag is not accepting this kind of value injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform arithmetic like this:

```
<#assign orderTotal=orderDetail.quantity * orderDetail.price>
```

Refer to your variable like this:

```
<td>${orderTotal}</td>
```

Or just:

```
<td>${orderDetail.quantity * orderDetail.price}</td>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. It throws parse exception like "You can't use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only needed where otherwise static text is expected, i.e, outside FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)"

Comment: @chellapandik no problem (it's been a few years since I worked with freemarker, but I'm about to get back into it, so it was good to refresh my memory!)

Comment: So you may want to edit your answer to remove the `${}` from the `#assign`. BTW, you can easily check your syntax at http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/.